# SwiftUI DatePicker on MacOS crashes on run - is it just me?

Tags: macos, swiftui, datepicker

Converting a small MacOS form style app to a MacOS SwiftUI app.  I added a DatePicker and the app started crashing.  Reduced it to the following reproducible minimum code. If either of the .padding() or the Text("Second Row") is removed or commented out.  The app loads OK.  Anyone with greater experience provide some assistance ?  In case it is relevant this on being done on Catalina 10.15.7, Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e).

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var thisDate: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.0)
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      VStack {
        HStack {
          DatePicker("Pick", selection: $thisDate)
            .padding()
        }
      }
      Text("Second row")
    }
  }
}
```

In the app, the crash record shows that it is whilst it is trying to do the layout but as this case, it is during the app startup process.

Comment: All I can contribute is that it works well on macos 12.beta, using xcode 13.beta.
So maybe it was a bug in earlier xcode, although the code looks ok to me.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure that it looked like Xcode bug, but best to have is validated by someone else.

Comment: Unrelated but `timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.0` is redundant.

Comment: Old habits ... ;-0....I see Date() does just the same thing.  Thanks.